# Symfony: How to read a table inside a html.twig file and export it in excel?

Tags: php, html, excel, symfony

My excel bundle works if I export from the database, but I need to export the html because I have filters on the table that the user can change.

In the controller I wrote:

```
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("html");


   $result = $objReader->load('AppBundle::report.html.twig');

  $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();
```

But symfony is saying: Could not open AppBundle::report.html.twig for reading! File does not exist.

Anyone know hot to do it?
Thanks

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Do you really believe that twig template change content when user change filter?

Comment: I just started programming so some things are still hard to understand for me, so u think is not possible to do it?

Comment: html changes! so i need to take the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `load` method of `$objReader` **will not resolve** path to your twig-template. Only native Symfony components/classes can do it. `PHPExcel` is a third-party library and knows nothing about symfony app structure. So, you should pass full path to your template:

```
$objReader->load('/some/path/here/report.html.twig');
```

Second (as @Malcolm mentioned) - twig-file is just a template. It's filled with some logics and data which is passed to it generates some outout. Do you really think that you can load some data from template? If you want to generate xls-file basing on user filter - you should pass user filter to server, select data according to the filter and generate an xls-file on this data. This is **the right way**.